# What's the name of these transformations.

Tags: terminology, tensors

I was self-studying Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds and
on page 89, two transformations $f_*$ and $f^{*}$ are defined as the following. 
Given a differentiable function $f:\mathbf{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbf{R}^m$, and a k-form $\omega$ on $\mathbf{R}^m$,
$f_*:\mathbf{R}^n_{\;p}\rightarrow\mathbf{R}^m_{\;f(p)}$ is defined as $f_*(v_p)=(Df(p)(v))_{f(p)}$

and
 $f^{*}:\Omega^{k}(\mathbf{R}^{m}_{\;f(p)})\rightarrow\Omega^k(\mathbf{R}^{n}_{\;p})$ is defined to satisfy $f^{*}\omega(p)(v_1,...,v_k)=\omega(f(p))(f_*(v_1),...,f_*(v_k)).$
I'd like to know what $f_*$ and $f^*$ are called.

Comment: Push-forward and pull-back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation $f_*$ is called a **pushforward** - it *pushes* objects from the domain *forward* to the codomain. That is, $f_*$ is covariant; it goes in the same direction as $f$.

The transformation $f^*$ is called a **pullback** - it *pulls* objects from the codomain *back* to the domain. That is, $f^*$ is contravariant; it goes in the opposite direction to $f$.